как мне сделать что бы при добавлении в таблицу число было больше предыдущего на 1?
Мне нужно сделать так что бы при добавлении в таблицу новой строчки, в столбце "ProductID", каждое значение было больше предыдущего. Что мне нужно написать в newProduct.ProductID = ?
 private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     var dataSet = (FloralDataSet)FindResource("floralDataSet");

     try
     {
         var newProduct = dataSet.Product.NewProductRow();

         newProduct.ProductID = 
         newProduct.ProductName = "Название";
         newProduct.Unit = "Колличество";
         newProduct.Quantity = "Качество";
         newProduct.PricePerUnit = 0;

         dataSet.Product.AddProductRow(newProduct);
         productDataGrid.SelectedItem = newProduct;

         MessageBox.Show("Пожалуйста, заполните данные для новой записи.", "Добавление записи", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
     }
     catch (SqlException ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Произошла ошибка при добавлении записи: " + ex.Message, "Ошибка добавления записи", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
     }
 }


var maxProductId = dataSet.Product.Max(p => (int?) p.ProductID); Чтобы узнать максимальный id

newProduct.ProductID = (maxProductId ?? 0) + 1; устанавливаем id у новой записи

@Deniska SosiSka спасибо!

Добавил как ответ

Очень сомнительный подход, особенно если к таблице имеется многопользовательский доступ. Возьмём вариант, когда хотя бы 2 человека одновременно пытаются добавить запись - Вы получите 2 одинаковых значения в поле ProductID. Если оно в БД является первичным ключом - будет ошибка. Для этого придуман AUTOINCREMENT для PRIMARY KEY полей БД, база сама следит за заполнением первичного ключа, часто предоставляя инструменты для получения только что вставленного или следующего значения

Для назначения у новой строки следующего по порядку id, Вам необходимо сначала узнать максимальный id в таблице. Вы можете сделать это при помощи LINQ:
var maxProductId = dataSet.Product.Max(p => p.ProductID);

После чего, присвойте новой строке значение id больше на 1:
newProduct.ProductID = maxProductId + 1;


Если подразумевается что в Вашей таблице не присутствуют строки по умолчанию, необходимо обработать возможный null:
var maxProductId = dataSet.Product.Max(p => (int?) p.ProductID);

newProduct.ProductID = (maxProductId ?? 0) + 1;

